# How to store user settings in excel add-in

Tags: excel, vba

I've built an Excel add-in that I would like to distribute to a few team members. There is a field (a key) that the user will need to provide. I have a user form that the user can use to enter in their unique key. I'd like to store that key as a variable within the add-in and don't know how to do it. I see a worksheet object within the add-in. Is there a way to store the variable there? The add-in will be used in multiple files, so I can't sore it in a specific file.

Comment: What's the key for? What problem are you trying to solve? How secure does it need to be? Have you tried storing it *anywhere*?

Comment: It doesn't need to be that secure. The key is used within the string of a call to get a csv. The key will determine the scope of the csv being pulled. Ideally, the user will install the add-in, then store their key through a user form. And when they run the other macros within the add-in it can reference that key. The accessed data isn't that sensative, so I'm not worried about security.

Comment: I believe you could have a dedicated table in one of the add-in's `Worksheet` own modules, to hold your settings. Or, if it's just one value, you could name the range that contains the value, and retrieve it with e.g. `AppSettings.Range("UserKey").Value`, assuming the worksheet is properly renamed to `AppSettings`. Or, ... or, or, or - there's just too many ways to solve that problem - you need to get stumped on a more specific programming issue to make a good, answerable SO question.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to persist user settings across sessions is to use VBA's SaveSetting and GetSetting to store and retrieve the key from the registry.
If you just want to store it within a single Excel session then use a Global/Public variable.